# supervisorctl error (xml parser) in otherwise working local configuration

Tags: python, flask, supervisord

This is a real head-scratcher for me. Don't know where to start, please help.

I have a local environment running nginx, and gunicorn under supervisor on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Everything is working fine except for supervisorctl:

```
campus-016-065:config [user]$ supervisorctl -s unix:///.../.../Flasl_Proj.sock
error: <class 'xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError'>, mismatched tag: line 10, column 4: file: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py line: 557
supervisor>
```

This doesn't really seem like a configuration problem to me, especially when everything else is working, so... what exactly is going wrong, and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

```
>cat supervisord.conf

[supervisord]
directory=/Users/[user]/.../.../Flask_Proj/
user=[user]
nodaemon=false

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///Users/[user]/.../.../Flask_Proj/
prompt=Flask_Proj

[include]
files=/Users/[user]/.../.../Flask_Proj/config/Flask_Proj.conf
```

---

```
>cat Flask_Proj.conf

[program:Flask_Proj]
command=/Users/[user]/.../.../Flask_Proj/config/gunicorn_start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=991
stopsignal=KILL
```

---

```
>cat gunicorn_start

#!/usr/bin/env bash
export FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_NAME="Project Name"
export FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_ROOT=/Users/[user]/.../.../.../
export FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_DIR=${FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_ROOT}FLASK_PROJ/
export FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_CONFIG=${FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_DIR}config/
export PYTHONPATH=$FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_ROOT:$PYTHONPATH
export FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_VENV=/Users/[user]/.virtualenvs/Flask_Proj-env/
export FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_SOCK=${FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_ROOT}Flask_Proj.sock
export FLASK_PROJ_WSGI_MOD="FLask_Proj:app"
export FLASK_PROJ_USER=[user]
export FLASK_PROJ_GROUP=staff
export FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_RUNDIR=$(dirname $FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_SOCK)
export FLASK_PROJ_GUNICORN_LOGS=${FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_DIR}logs/
export FLASK_PROJ_GUNICORN_LOGLEVEL="debug"
export FLASK_PROJ_GUNICORN_PROCESS="gunicorn_Flask_Proj_flask"

echo "Starting $FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_NAME as `whoami`"
source ${FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_VENV}bin/activate

test -d $FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_RUNDIR || mkdir -p $FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_RUNDIR
exec ${FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_VENV}bin/gunicorn -c ${FLASK_PROJ_FLASK_CONFIG}gunicorn.conf.py ${FLASK_PROJ_WSGI_MOD}
```

Comment: Please add more information, are you using any configuration file for supervisord? if it's an XML file, you're probably missing a root node for the xml tree. You're not showing running a configuration file at all above, so please add more information. Also, note that supervisorctl should be used after you start supervisord (think of supervisord as the server and the *ctl as the client allowing control of supervisord. If supervisord wasn't started, supervisordctl will fail.

Comment: Okay -- Editted to show configuration file -- base configuration file just has an [include] that points to, and successfully finds that file. 

It is not an XML file -- I am not using an xml file anywhere in the configuration, which is pretty much why I am here

And yes, supervisord was up and running when I attempted to supervisorctl

Comment: you're not showing anything new.. did you save the edits?

Comment: ^^ was still editing -- it's up now

Comment: i'm thinking there's something to do with calling supervisordctl with the socket. call supervisordctl with the same -c <conf file> parameter as when you start the supervisord process.

Comment: Well, yes, it does have to do with that -- calling supervisord with localhost:9001 and supervisorctl with localhost:9001 works fine. But... this doesn't necessarily help. I'm thinking that if supervisord is run as root, and the socket is created by a script running as a specific user (www-data), then this may be a weird manifestation of a permission error

Comment: not sure where this stands, if you found a solution, please post and accept your own solution (i.e. state that it was a user permissions issue, etc..)

Comment: well ... no, I didn't solve it. I ended up abandoning the problem and just using localhost on the server rather than a unix socket.

If I were to suggest a way that someone *might* solve this problem, it would be to make sure that the supervisor process user and group has read/write access along the whole cd path from executable run location, to the executable location, to the application location.